# How do I dynamically add form fields (2 in one click) to my form in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have 3 fields in my form I have a submit button and a button to "Add additional fields" I have the additional fields in a partial.

I am a beginner to a lot of this and am stuck with a beginner question: My question is :

When I click the "Add additional field" button, what is the process to add the additional fields? Preferably not re-rendering the form, which i believe requires javascript.

Comment: Put your Partial page in div and initially set style display none for the div. ...And when you click on "Add additional field" button show the div using javascript...

Answer (score 0):

In html file

```
<div id= "show_page" style= "display:none">
   <%= render partial: "your_partial_page" %> 
</div>
link_to "Add additional field", '#', id: 'add_fields'

$('#add_fields').click(function(){ //add this code to your javascript file
  $('#show_page').show();
});
```